# MySQL Indexing Keys Fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Can anyone explain me what happen and what the best way is to create the third table on the next clausule.

Should the this :

```
INDEX (id),
        INDEX (id_producto),
        INDEX (id_usuario)
```

be removed?

```
CREATE TABLE producto (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    precio DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE usuario (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE ordenes_productos (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_producto INT NOT NULL,
    id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_hora DATETIME NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id, id_producto, id_usuario),
    INDEX (id),
    INDEX (id_producto),
    INDEX (id_usuario),

    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES producto(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Thanks you all.

Comment: clarify your question plz to get some more helps. what do you mean by *create de third table on the next clausule* ?

Comment: Hi @Pokies, I am making reference to the Create Clausule of the table 'ordenes_productos', in that one is my confussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id, id_producto, id_usuario),
INDEX (id),
INDEX (id_producto),
INDEX (id_usuario),
FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES producto(id),
FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id)
```

Analysis:

- An `AUTO_INCREMENT` is usually "unique"
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, "unique"
- Starting a compound `PRIMARY KEY` with something that is unique does not make much sense.
- `FOREIGN KEYs` need indexes.  That is, `FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario)...` needs `INDEX (id_usuario)`.
- The `WHERE` clause in `SELECTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs` should be studied to determine what indexes are needed.  (In the absence of showing us those, I will assume there are no critical ones.)

Considering all of the above, I recommend these indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX (id_producto),
INDEX (id_usuario)
```

But...  There is another consideration.  Is this a "many-to-many mapping" between `usuario` and `producto`?  If so, then the pair `(usario, producto)` is "unique"?  If yes to all these, then:

```
CREATE TABLE ordenes_productos (
    id_producto INT NOT NULL,
    id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_hora DATETIME NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(id_producto, id_usuario),  -- map one way
    INDEX      (id_usuario, id_producto),  -- map the other way
    FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES producto(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

[More details on many-to-many](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table);

On to another topic...

```
CREATE TABLE producto (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    precio DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Are there any other fields in this table?  Are you just 'normalizing' a price?  It is not a good idea to normalize any "continuous" value (date, number, float, etc).  Caveat:  this comment about normalization and my comment about many-to-many are incompatible.

`usuario` is different (with respect to normalization) in that `VARCHAR` is not 'continuous' and `VARCHAR` is much bigger.